# Nested collection cloud firestore always loaded?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Does Google's Cloud firestore download all nested data form a queried document?

Is the content of collection 'content' (which is inside the article document) always loaded when I query for the document in the picture?

[image: a screenshot of firestore]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Queries in Firestore don't consider documents in subcollections, just documents in the collection that's named in the query.

Comment: Thanks, do you also have a source for this?

Comment: That's just how Firestore works.  I am on the Firebase team, so I have a lot of experience with this.